# Erroneous 5169 error fix?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error message while expanding transaction logs on my server on several of my databases.  The message is:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Blah] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'Blah_Log', MAXSIZE = 16384KB , FILEGROWTH = 4096KB )
GO


Msg 5169, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
FILEGROWTH cannot be greater than MAXSIZE for file 'Blah_Log'.
```

I am not setting FILEGROWTH to be greater than MAXSIZE (unless more coffee is in order and I'm just not seeing it?).  Has anyone else encountered this situation, and if so, what was the fix?  I have tried this using the SQL Server GUI and scripting, and getting the same message on the problem databases in question.  Any help would be greatly appreciated by this newbie.  Thank you.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: What are the *current* settings? Have you tried setting the size in one ALTER and the filegrowth separately?

Comment: The version of SQL Server is 2008 R2.  The current settings were for an initial size of 4 MB with an autogrowth of 100 MB increments with an unlimited capacity.  Aaron, your suggestion of setting the size and the filegrowth separately worked beautifully.  Can you explain what was happening? Thank you both very much for your help.

Comment: @Pam it's possible that internally there is a fixed order in which the ALTER DATABASE command gets processed: filegrowth must occur before maxsize, and your existing max size is too small (or max size of 16 MB - which sounds dangerous, btw - was checked against the existing 100 MB autogrow, not the new one in your alter command).

Comment: @Aaron, that explanation makes a lot of sense.  As a little background, this database is a 50 MB database with a 4 MB transaction log that has held at that level for quite some time with no expected changes in the forseeable future.  The transaction log was initially set for 100 MB autogrowth with unlimited capacity which seemed inappropriate, given the limited size and activity.  I really appreciate your help with the fix and insight into what was happening.  It's been a good learning experience for me.